# call two different functions on same object in a pipe (%>%)

Tags: r, magrittr

I want to know if there is a way to call both `html_name()` and `html_text` (from `rvest` package) and store the two different results from inside the same pipe (`magrittr::%>%`)

Here is an example:

```
uniprot_ac <- "P31374"

GET(paste0("https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/", uniprot_ac, ".xml")) %>%
    content(as = "raw", content = "text/xml") %>%
    read_html %>%
    html_nodes(xpath = '//recommendedname/* |
               //name[@type="primary"] | //comment[@type="function"]/text |
               //comment[@type="interaction"]/text')
```

At this point I want to get both the tag names from `html_name()`

```
[1] "fullname" "ecnumber" "name"     "text"
```

AND the tag content without having to create a separate object by rewriting the entire pipe to just change the last line to `html_text()`

```
[1] "Serine/threonine-protein kinase PSK1"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
[2] "2.7.11.1"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
[3] "PSK1"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
[4] "Serine/threonine-protein kinase involved ... ...
```

Desired output can be something like this, either vector or data.frame doesn't matter

```
  [1] fullname: "Serine/threonine-protein kinase PSK1"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  [2] ecnumber: "2.7.11.1"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  [3] Name: "PSK1"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  [4] Text: "Serine/threonine-protein kinase involved ... ...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe a bit of a hack, but you can use parenthesized anonymous functions in pipes:

```
library("magrittr")
library("httr")
library("xml2")
library("rvest")

uniprot_ac <- "P31374"

GET(paste0("https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/", uniprot_ac, ".xml")) %>%
  content(as = "raw", content = "text/xml") %>%
  read_html %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = '//recommendedname/* |
             //name[@type="primary"] | //comment[@type="function"]/text |
             //comment[@type="interaction"]/text') %>% 
  (function(x) list(name = html_name(x), text = html_text(x)))
#$name
#[1] "fullname" "ecnumber" "name"     "text"    
#
#$text
#[1] "Serine/threonine-protein kinase PSK1"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
#[2] "2.7.11.1"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
#[3] "PSK1"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
#[4] "Serine/threonine-protein kinase involved in the control of sugar metabolism and translation. Phosphorylates UGP1, which is required for normal glycogen and beta-(1,6)-glucan synthesis. This phosphorylation shifts glucose partitioning toward cell wall glucan synthesis at the expense of glycogen synthesis."
```

Alternatively, you might be able to do something more elegant with the `purrr` package, but I don't see a reason why you want to load an entire package just to do that.

**Edit**
As noted by @MrFlick in the comments, the dot (`.`) placeholder can do the same thing if properly put in curly brackets.

```
GET(paste0("https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/", uniprot_ac, ".xml")) %>%
  content(as = "raw", content = "text/xml") %>%
  read_html %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = '//recommendedname/* |
             //name[@type="primary"] | //comment[@type="function"]/text |
             //comment[@type="interaction"]/text') %>% 
  {list(name = html_name(.), text = html_text(.))}
```

This is arguably the more magrittr-idiomatic way of doing it, and it *is* actually documented in `help("%>%")`.

Comment: thanks i accepted this one cause it is more "compact" with the anon function and it indeed solve the problem within the pipe

Comment: Am i missing something, or why aren't people recommending `{ list(name = html_name(.), text = html_text(.))}`. You don't really need function.

Comment: No you do need a function otherwise by just calling `list()` the `xml_nodeset` from `html_nodes()` will also be stored in the list (first element)

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks! I actually tried that, without the curly brackets, and got the result corresponding to `list(., f(.), g(.))` much like @likeeatingpizza describes. I didn't readily know how to fix that, so I opted for the anon function. I've edited the post with that as well.

Comment: Oh yes I was also getting the nodeset because I was missing the brackets around the whole expression. Now I wonder, using this solution, is there a way to continue the pipe and `paste` the two list elements together (like the output in my first post)? This works `mapply(paste, sep = ": ", prot_info[[1]], prot_info[[2]])` but only if I use `prot_info` to store the LHS result of the pipe...

Answer (score 4):

You could make a custom function that takes in your `html_nodes` object and carries out any desired operations on it:

```
html_name_text <- function(nodes) {
    list(html_name(nodes), html_text(nodes))
}

GET(paste0("https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/", uniprot_ac, ".xml")) %>%
    content(as = "raw", content = "text/xml") %>%
    read_html %>%
    html_nodes(xpath = '//recommendedname/* |
               //name[@type="primary"] | //comment[@type="function"]/text |
               //comment[@type="interaction"]/text') %>%
    html_name_text()

[[1]]
[1] "fullname" "ecnumber" "name"     "text"    

[[2]]
[1] "Serine/threonine-protein kinase PSK1"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
[2] "2.7.11.1"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
[3] "PSK1"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
[4] "Serine/threonine-protein kinase involved in the control of sugar metabolism and translation. Phosphorylates UGP1, which is required for normal glycogen and beta-(1,6)-glucan synthesis. This phosphorylation shifts glucose partitioning toward cell wall glucan synthesis at the expense of glycogen synthesis."
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a `purrr` approach which returns a `tibble`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

uniprot_ac <- "P31374"
read_html(paste0("https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/", uniprot_ac, ".xml")) %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = '//recommendedname/* |
               //name[@type="primary"] | //comment[@type="function"]/text |
               //comment[@type="interaction"]/text') %>% 
  map(~ list(name = html_name(.), text = html_text(.))) %>%
  bind_rows
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   name     text                                                            
#>   <chr>    <chr>                                                           
#> 1 fullname Serine/threonine-protein kinase PSK1                            
#> 2 ecnumber 2.7.11.1                                                        
#> 3 name     PSK1                                                            
#> 4 text     Serine/threonine-protein kinase involved in the control of suga~
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use bracket after your pipe, to store the current result in a tempory object (if required), and then to calculate the different results you want to:

```
GET(paste0("https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/", uniprot_ac, ".xml")) %>%
    content(as = "raw", content = "text/xml") %>%
    read_html %>%
    html_nodes(xpath = '//recommendedname/* |
               //name[@type="primary"] | //comment[@type="function"]/text |
               //comment[@type="interaction"]/text') %>% {
    list(name = html_name(.), text = html_text(.))
    }
```

Just for your information, sometimes you will need to pass through a tempory object, like in this example :

```
iris %>% 
  select(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width) %>% {
     temp <- .
     bind_rows(temp %>% filter(Sepal.Length > 5), 
               temp %>% filter(Sepal.Width <= 3))
} %>% 
  dim()
```

In this case, if you replace `temp` with `.` directly, it will not work.

Comment: Nice option! Is there a reason you'd want to define `temp` as a temporary variable instead of just using `.` directly? They seem to give the same results in this example ...

Comment: you're right, in this case, using directly the `.` is more elegant ! (I edited my answer)
In some case, if you want to make some manipulations on the current result, with other pipes and functions for instance, passing through a tempory object will be necessary.

Comment: I'm trying to also paste the list elements together in the same pipe, but even using a temp object I get an error `x <- . %>%; mapply(paste, sep = ": ", x[[1]], x[[2]])}` `Error .. ... could not find function "%>%<-"`

Comment: `.` did not work here because when given as the lhs of a pipe chain a function sequence will be produced (roughly, a composed function). I will work fine if instead of `.` you use `(.)`, `{.}`, `force(.)` or `identity(.)` for instance.

Comment: Thank a lot for the tip @Moody_Mudskipper.

Answer (score 3):

Without additional package nor much braces and dots play you could do :

```
nodes %>% lapply(list(html_name, html_text), function(x,y) x(y), .)
# [[1]]
# [1] "fullname" "ecnumber" "name"     "text"    
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "Serine/threonine-protein kinase PSK1"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
# [2] "2.7.11.1"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
# [3] "PSK1"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
# [4] "Serine/threonine-protein kinase involved in the control of sugar
```

Or the following, slightly more compact but with braces:

```
nodes %>% {lapply(list(html_name, html_text), do.call, list(.))}
```

I would use `purrr` though and loop on functions and pass these function to `exec` along with `.` as the parameter :

```
library(purrr)
nodes %>% map(list(html_name, html_text), exec, .)
```

(same output)

**data**

```
library("magrittr")
library("httr")
library("xml2")
library("rvest")
nodes <- GET(paste0("https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/", uniprot_ac, ".xml")) %>%
  content(as = "raw", content = "text/xml") %>%
  read_html %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = '//recommendedname/* |
             //name[@type="primary"] | //comment[@type="function"]/text |
             //comment[@type="interaction"]/text')
```

Comment: +1 On the `exec` approach. Can you elaborate on what exactly is going on there? This is the first time I've seen `exec`. Or where I can find more information, examples, blog posts, or tutorials on its usage?

Comment: Try `?rlang::exec`, `exec(max, 1,3,2)` is equivalent to `max(1,3,2)` . It's not useful in that simple case of course, but when dealing with variables containing functions as is the case here it becomes interesting. In base `R` we could have done `eval(call("max",1,3,2))` or `do.call("max",list(1,3,3))`. `exec` also supports splicing and quasi quotation (`!!` and `!!!`). `map` + `exec` is also the recommended replacement of `invoke_map` (see `?purrr::invoke_map`) which was pretty much initially designed for OP's case, so I think my solution here is idiomatic in term of tidyverse programming.